# ggplot2 bar plot, x axis not in order

Tags: r

```
a <- matrix(0,2,10)
a[1,] <-c(5.165815, 0.1544952, 1.375914, 0.3414154, 13.78202, 17.34233, 3.58367, 2.33674, -0.1583099, 1.26791)
a[2,] <-c(3.717303, 1.244664, -0.3640652, -1.925349, 3.510475, -0.8143187, 3.871202, 1.268744, -2.367854, -2.794683)

a<-data.frame(a)

colnames(a) <- c("ATL","ORD","LAX","DFW","JFK","EWR","IAH","DTW","MSP","MIA")
spc_data <- c('ASO4IJ','AECIJ')

rownames(a) <- spc_data
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

a$species <- spc_data
data_1.m <- melt(a, id.var = 'species')

dat11 <- subset(data_1.m,value >= 0)
dat12 <- subset(data_1.m,value < 0)

p <- ggplot(col = 'rainbow', width = 1) + 
geom_bar(data = dat11, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=species),stat = "identity") +
geom_bar(data = dat12, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=species),stat = "identity") +
xlab("Airport") +
ylab("mass (ng/m3)")
print(p)
```

if we comment out geom_bar(data = dat12, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=species),stat = "identity") +

the x-axis is in the order that I want, however, if we add it back in, x axis would be in alphabetical order. From previous post, some one told me it is a factor issue, however, levels(dat11$variable) levels(dat12$variable) and levels(data_1.m$variable) are all the same as 
"ATL" "ORD" "LAX" "DFW" "JFK" "EWR" "IAH" "DTW" "MSP" "MIA". I don't understand why it is not following the levels(dat12$variable), but alphabetically?

any suggestion?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to draw? You are stacking layers in an usual way and i'm not sure how you are meant to interpret the bar height. Do you just want the tallest on top? Things are always easier if you just have one data.frame with a grouping variable rather than adding separate layers. The problem with different data parameters on different layers, is that R needs to merge the two factors, and by default it does by sorting the levels. You can explicitly set the order with [x_scale_discrete](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_discrete.html)

Comment: thanks, I trie scale_x_discrete(limits = ), and it works.

Comment: Note that you can also set both to be ordered factors, and then set the levels to be the same, e.g. `dat11$variable = ordered(dat11$variable); dat12$variable = ordered(dat12$variable); levels(dat12$variable) = levels(dat11$variable)`.